# Webpack throwing Error: Cannot find module './locale' after switching project to windows

Tags: webpack, create-react-app

Downloaded my repo to my windows machine after working on my last work project's Mac, after `yarn install`ing and getting a succesful compile, I'm getting a

```
Error: Cannot find module './locale'
```

at runtime, not seeing much online other than bug reports, anyone encounter this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding this plugin in your webpack configuration file:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\.\/locale$/, 'empty-module', false, /js$/)
]
```

Make sure everything works in runtime of course

Comment: I tried adding this to all `plugins:` entries of my `react-scripts` webpack config, but it didnt work, its throwing another error @ `npm start`

Comment: `18 verbose node v10.15.3`
`19 verbose npm  v6.4.1`
`20 error code ELIFECYCLE`
`21 error errno 1`
`22 error eva01@0.1.0 start: react-scripts start`
`22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the eva01@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]`

Comment: This not see this `Cannot read property 'tap' of undefined` before that log

Comment: Which webpack version you are running?

Answer (score 0):

it's a new issue.

try downgrade your `moment` version
in `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {

    "moment": "2.24.0",

  },
"resolutions": {
    "moment": "2.24.0"
  }
```

[see github issue page here](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/4216)

Comment: This seems to be a 2017 issue, I tried this anyway and it did not work